# Nuxt.js | Отправка Ajax-запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, http, nuxt.js

Делал get запрос к https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users с помощью axios.
Все работает, отправил вот так:

```
this.$axios.get('/users').then(data=>{console.log(data)});
```

Но подумал о том, что в дальнейшем нужно передавать также и headers.
Можете сказать, как максимально подробно выполнить ajax запрос с помощью axios. Знаю что есть axios.create, но я не понимаю как он работает
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В get/delete есть 2 параметра (ссылка, конфиг):

```
this.$axios.get('https://test.com', {
  params: {
    'page': '5' // Это те, что в ссылке через ?
  },
  headers: {
    'Something': 'value'
  },
  progress: false, // Скрывает прогресс-бар от Nuxt
})
```

В post/put/patch 3 (ссылка, данные/тело, конфиг):

```
this.$axios.post('https://test.com', {
    'some_data': 'value'
  }, {
    headers: {
      'Something': 'value'
    },
    progress: false,
  }
)
```

В конфиге передаете параметры, какие хотите. В 99% конфиг не используется.
Не знаю, зачем Вам в отдельном запросе передавать заголовки. Если для токена нужно, то используйте интерцепторы: [Документация](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).